# How can I block my hacked Google account?

Tags: google-account, hacked

My Google account was hacked. I tried resetting my password, but Google takes 3-5 days to do this.

In the meantime, I want the account turned off completely so the hackers do not do more damage.

How do I ensure this?

I cannot find this answer on Google, nor can I find an email address to ask them.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do anything to an account you don't control. Your question is a little unclear, but as I understand you, right now, you don't control your account, because you don't have access to it until you get a new password. So, you can't do anything to the account.

Even if you did have access to the account, there is no such thing as "turning off" a Google account. You can change the password or close the account permanently, but you can't temporarily disable it.